# React Event Handling: Marking as Favorite item on Instant in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-state-management

[image]

So in my recipe App, users are able to mark or unmark recipes as their favorite. 
The only thing I can't wrap my head around is How to make it instant. my current code supports makes a post call to mark the recipe as favorite but you see the change of  icon (i.e the filled one) they have to refresh the page.
I do need some suggestion on how can I make it work on the click.

Here is my code:

```
class CuisineViewById extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: {},
            access_token: '',
        };
        this.toggleFavorite = this.toggleFavorite.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getUser(() => {
            this.props.getAccessToken(this.props.user.profile.sub, () => {
                console.log(this.props.user);
                this.props.getCuisineById(this.props.match.params.id, this.props.accessToken);
                this.props.getFavoriteRecipes(this.props.accessToken);
            });
        });
    }

    toggleFavorite(userID, recipeID, marked) {
        const userpreference = {
            userid: userID,
            recipe: recipeID,
            favorite: marked
        };

        axios
            .post('/api/userpreference', userpreference, {
                headers: {'access_token': this.props.access_token}
            })
            .then(res => console.log(res));
    }

    displayFavorite = recipeId => {
        let favoriteRecipes = this.props.userPreferred;
        for (var i = 0; i < favoriteRecipes.length; i++) {
            if (favoriteRecipes[i].recipe === recipeId) {
                return true;
            } else {
            }
        }
    };

  render() {
       const that = this; 
       const {user} = this.props; 
       const {cuisine} = this.props; 

       return (
             <CuisineTileHeading
                 label={cuisine.label}
                 totalNoRecipes={cuisine.totalRecipes]}
                 key={cuisine.id}
             >
            {cuisine.recipes && cuisine.recipes.map(function(asset, index) 
                  {
                   let marked = recipe.isFavorite ? 'no' : 'yes';
                     return (
                        <RecipesCards
                           title={recipe.title}
                           description={recipe.description}
                           chef={recipe.owner}
                           lastUpdated={recipe.lastUpdated}
                           recipeType={recipe.assetType}
                           key={'RecipesCard' + index}
                           thumbnail={recipe.thumbnailBase64}
                           recipeId={recipe.id}
                           cuisine={cuisine}
                           favorite={that.displayFavorite(recipe.id)}
                           toggleFavorite={() =>
                                                        that.toggleFavorite(userId, recipe.id, marked)
                           }
                           />
                           );
            })}
      </CuisneTileHeading>
    )

  } 
}

const mapStateToProps = state = ({   
  cuisine : state.cuisine.cuisne, 
  user: state.user.user, 
  userPreferred: state.recipe.userPrefered, 
  accessToken: state.asset.accessToken

)}
```

In my component did mount, I am calling functions to get user information, then access token and then cuisines and then user favorite recipes.

toggleFavorite is the function that makes a recipe favorite or not favorite.

displayFavorite is a function that return either true or false is recipe id matches to the recipe ID store in userpreference object.

Comment: in my post call, If I call my this.props.getFavoriteRecipes(), it does works. But it take a little longer to turn the star yellow.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you compute that "this recipe is favorite" from a function that returns true or false.

ReactJS has no way to automatically trigger a re-rendering of the favorite icon since it is not linked to the recipe's state at all.

If you put "isFavorite" in the recipe's state and toggle that to true or false with the onClick event, which will change the recipe's state value for "isFavorite", React should know to call a re-render on the recipe card's icon ... then you just make sure it outputs the HTML for a filled icon when true and empty icon when false. React will know to re-render all DOM elements linked to that "slice" of the state, "isFavorite recipe" in this case.

TL;DR: leverage React's state concept instead of computing if the recipe is favorited by the user through a function which does not modify the state, since re-renders are done by React when the state changes.